# Having issues selecting next element in selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

When selecting another country, the list becomes visible. It works, however there's one issue. When selecting another county the very first item of its attached region must be displayed, instead of remained value.

I.e. when selecting `Germany`, `New York` must become invisible, and `Dresden` must become visible. I've been trying to do this for several hours with no luck. Any advice?

```js
$(function() {
  $("[name='country']").change(function() {
    // Target option
    var hiddenClass = 'hidden';
    var selected = $(this).find(':selected').data('country-id');

    // Hide all options
    $("[name='region']").find('option') // Find all options
      .addClass(hiddenClass) // Hide them all
      .each(function() {
        // Find current active
        if ($(this).data('country-id') == selected) {
          // Show currently matched against selection
          $(this).removeClass(hiddenClass);
        }
      });
  }).trigger('change');

});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
</script>

<select name="country">
  <option data-country-id="1">USA</option>
  <option data-country-id="2">Germany</option>
</select>

<select name="region">
  <option data-country-id="1">New York</option>
  <option data-country-id="1">California</option>
  <option data-country-id="1">Carolina</option>
  <option data-country-id="2">Dresden</option>
  <option data-country-id="2">Berlin</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because, although some of the `option` elements are hidden, they're still technically available in the DOM to be selected. To fix this you can force the selection to update to the first available `option` based on the given `country-id` value.

Also note that you can make your logic more succinct by using `filter()` instead of an `each()` loop. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("[name='country']").change(function() {
    var hiddenClass = 'hidden';
    var selected = $(this).find(':selected').data('country-id');
    
    $('[name="region"] option').addClass(hiddenClass)
      .filter(`[data-country-id="${selected}"]`).removeClass(hiddenClass)
      .first().prop('selected', true);
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>

<select name="country">
  <option data-country-id="1">USA</option>
  <option data-country-id="2" selected="true">Germany</option>
</select>

<select name="region">
  <option data-country-id="1">New York</option>
  <option data-country-id="1">California</option>
  <option data-country-id="1">Carolina</option>
  <option data-country-id="2">Dresden</option>
  <option data-country-id="2">Berlin</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Hovewer, will this be broken, say if there's a pre-selected option on document load? Say if on page load, the country is Germany and the region is Berlin (i.e corresponding option elements have `selected` attribute).

Comment: That will work absolutely fine as you're triggering the `change` event on load. I'll amend the snippet to show you this happening.

Comment: No no, I mean the case when both related items are pre-selected, like `<option data-country-id="2" selected="true">Germany</option>` and `<option data-country-id="2" selected="true">Berlin</option>`

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case you'd need to separate the logic under page load to not set the selected value.